trigger useEffect if any property in object changes except for a single property named 'id'
I have a useEffect in my component->
and data1 is an array of object.
Is there a way to trigger this useEffect only when properties inside this object is updated, except for one property-'id'.
useEffect(() => {
    prepareAdaptableOptions();
}, [JSON.stringify(data1), JSON.stringify(config1)]);


You could use Object.defineProperty(object, "id", {enumerable: false}) to make it so JSON.stringify result does not include the id or add a custom replacer function to remove the id from the output. Hovever using json output as an effect trigger is probably not the best approach in the first place
